# Is it possible to implement TypeScript library which support both JavaScript and TypeScript caller (like vue)?

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, vue.js

I'm curious about how to write libraries in TypeScript that work for both JavaScript and TypeScript because TypeScript is a better choice for engineering and is more friendly to IDE but JavaScript is more widely used.

I noticed that Vue was written in TypeScript and the developer said "Vue APIs are also designed to work the same way in both JavaScript and TypeScript as much as possible" in FAQs, and we can actually call Vue's API in JavaScript-written Vue projects like native.

Is there any guide or suggestion about how to do that?

update:
It's well-known that TS is compiled into JS before running. Because of the compiling process, something could change and some language features could have gone, so I think there could be some guidelines like "expose your TypeScript API like this, and they could be stably converted in JavaScript like this, so you can tell JS programmer to use them. " I do find some TS libraries expose their API through TS concepts and features like parameter decorators so it's hard to use them in JS

Comment: Typescript is compiled to JavaScript code. At runtime, it's all JavaScript.

Comment: TS-friendly lib is just .js + .d.ts files, this is what TS is compiled to. If you don't write it in TS, you have to write .d.ts files on your own

Comment: "*something could change and some language features could have gone*" - not really. It's just stripping out the types. The only things that really get "compiled" are `enum` declarations, and transpiling "new" JS syntax (`class`es, modules, generator functions, `async`/`await`) to ES5 or lower if you request *tsc* to do it; but that's just the same thing *babel* would do